# Cannot use VR Headset with Qualisys simultaneously due to IR interference

Tags: htc-vive, steam-vr, motion-capture

We have HTC Vive wireless headset with base stations set up in a room having Qualisys setup also for motion capturing. We need to create a scene inside Unity that can track the marker data and observe it in VR using SteamVR and Unity. But when I run the Unity program, the headset is not detected because of the interference.

We thought of tracking the headset using Qualisys instead of Base Stations by adding markers on the headset, but the problem with this approach is that SteamVR requires that Base Station should detect the headset all the time for the VR display to work, and we cannot use the base stations and Qualisys together. Was it possible earlier to decouple SteamVR and base stations in earlier versions of Vive?

We found this [thread](https://forum.htc.com/topic/6257-parallel-use-of-vive-and-qualisys-motion-capturing-causes-interference/) on the Vive forum that discusses the same problem, but no solution has been found. We saw this[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sj9RjimQ52A) made in 2016 having motion capturing inside VR.

Can anyone suggest some ideas on how to solve this problem, preferably not switching to another VR headset? Also, please correct us if we are wrong in any approach/assumption.